# which Forms libaray to use with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, forms, sqlalchemy, flask

I am working on a web app based on Flask and SQLAlchemy. Most of forms/models are related and therefore need to use a library that's flexible enough to handle multiple forms and allows easy overriding [or creation] of default widgets.

Can someone recommend a good forms library (other than formalchemy). I really liked django forms but wondering if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) should suit your taste, with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Might also want to mention Flask has an [extension](http://packages.python.org/Flask-WTF/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "deform" which currently powers repoze.BFG aka Pylons2.

It has some nice "magical" methods for creating collection of forms and adding more forms on the fly.

If you liked django then deform may be a good choice.